# How to get Value From Expandable Listview

Tags: android, json, expandablelistview

I have successfully get data in Array List from Api. But when i tried to get value of Expandable Child view , i am not getting proper value. please suggest where i wrong.
This is my whole implementation please give me suggestion where i wrong.

This is my code:

```
public class Ex_Lv extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ArrayList<ModelGroup> modelgroup = null;
    private ArrayList<ModelChild> modelchild = null;
    private ArrayList<Category> alCategory;
    private ArrayList<ArrayList<ModelChild>> ListChildXXXXXXXXX= null;
    String result;
    Toolbar toolbar;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_ex__lv);
        new AsyncGetExpandable().execute();

        initData();
        initUI();
    }

    private void initUI() {
        toolbar= (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbarrEx_Lw);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.icon_back_white);
        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                onBackPressed();
            }
        });
    }

    private void initData() {
        alCategory = new ArrayList<>();

        modelgroup = new ArrayList<ModelGroup>();
        modelchild = new ArrayList<ModelChild>();//ArrayList<ArrayList<ChildTerbaru>>>();

        ListChildXXXXXXXXX = new ArrayList<ArrayList<ModelChild>>();
    }

    public class AsyncGetExpandable extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, AsyncTaskResult<Object>> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            findViewById(R.id.rlProgress).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        protected AsyncTaskResult<Object> doInBackground(Void... params) {
            BufferedReader in = null;

            try {
                HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
                HttpConnectionParams
                        .setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, 20000);
                HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, 20000);
                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);

                String url = AppConstants.URL_GET_CATEGORIES;

                if (AppConstants.DEBUG) Log.v(AppConstants.DEBUG_TAG, "CATEGORIES URL : " + url);

                HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);

                request.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
                request.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
                request.setHeader("token", "Cq2uOA1Rvu5Pvtnt6XZifC9CAyNR4ISS3MsS6jDZ");

                if (AppConstants.DEBUG)
                    Log.v(AppConstants.DEBUG_TAG, "BEARER : ");

                HttpResponse response = null;

                response = client.execute(request);

                in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response
                        .getEntity().getContent()));

                StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
                String line = "";
                String NL = System.getProperty("line.separator");

                while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + NL);
                }

                in.close();

                result = sb.toString();

                if (AppConstants.DEBUG)
                    Log.v(AppConstants.DEBUG_TAG, "CATEGORIES RESPONSE : " + result);

                return new AsyncTaskResult<Object>(result);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (in != null) {
                    try {
                        in.close();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }

            return new AsyncTaskResult<Object>("OK");
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(AsyncTaskResult<Object> result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            findViewById(R.id.rlProgress).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            if (result.getError() != null) {

            } else {
                try {
                    String resulta = result.getResult().toString();
                    JSONObject jsonRoot = null;
                    try {
                        jsonRoot = new JSONObject(resulta);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    JSONArray jsonArray = null;
                    try {
                        jsonArray = jsonRoot.getJSONArray("category");
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                      ModelGroup LT = null;
                    ModelChild CT = null;
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        modelchild = new ArrayList<ModelChild>();
                        JSONObject jsonObject = null;
                        try {
                            jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        LT = new ModelGroup();
                        try {
                            LT.setCat_name(jsonObject.getString("category_name_en"));
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        try {
                            LT.setCat_id(jsonObject.getString("id"));
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        modelgroup.add(LT);

                        // for (int j = 0; j < jsonArray.length(); j++) {
                        CT = new ModelChild();
                        JSONObject jsonObject2=null;
                        JSONArray  jsonArray1= jsonObject.getJSONArray("sub_category");

                        for(int j=0; j < jsonArray1.length();j++){
                            jsonObject2= jsonArray1.getJSONObject(j);
                        }

                        try {
                            CT.setSub_category_name_en(jsonObject2.getString("sub_category_name_en"));
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        try {
                            CT.setCat_id(jsonObject.getString("id"));
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        modelchild.add(CT);//get(i).get(i).add(CT);

                        ListChildXXXXXXXXX.add(modelchild);
                        ExpandableListView list = (ExpandableListView)findViewById(R.id.lvExp) ;

                        list.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                            @Override
                            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                                v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                                return false;
                            }
                        });

                        final ExpandableAdpeter adapter = new ExpandableAdpeter(getApplicationContext(), modelgroup, ListChildXXXXXXXXX);
                        list.setAdapter(adapter);


                       /* list.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
                                //get the group header
                                ModelChild CT;
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),modelchild.get(groupPosition).getSub_category_name_en(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                return false;
                            }
                        });*/


                        // setOnGroupClickListener listener for group heading click
                        list.setOnGroupClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, long id) {
                                //get the group header

                                ModelGroup  LT=modelgroup.get(groupPosition);
                                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), " Header is :: " + LT.getCat_name(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                return false;
                            }
                        });

                    }
                }catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }
            }
        }
    }` 

    **But i want to print value of Group and related Child **

    list.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
            //get the group header
            ModelChild CT;
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),modelchild.get(groupPosition).getSub_category_name_en(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            return false;
        }
    });

    // setOnGroupClickListener listener for group heading click
    list.setOnGroupClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, long id) {
            //get the group header

            ModelGroup  LT=modelgroup.get(groupPosition);
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), " Header is :: " + LT.getCat_name(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return false;
        }
    });

}
```

This is my Adapter where i set getcat_name and get_id:
Please Give me suggestion

```
  public class ExpandableAdpeter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
    Context context;
    ArrayList<ModelGroup> ListTerbaru;
    ArrayList<ArrayList<ModelChild>> ListChildTerbaru;
    int count;

    public ExpandableAdpeter (Context context, ArrayList<ModelGroup>ListTerbaru, ArrayList<ArrayList<ModelChild>> ListChildTerbaru){
        this.context=context;
        this.ListTerbaru=ListTerbaru;
        this.ListChildTerbaru=ListChildTerbaru;
//      this.count=ListTerbaru.size();
//      this.count=ListChildTerbaru.size();
    }
    @Override
    public boolean areAllItemsEnabled()
    {
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public ModelChild getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return ListChildTerbaru.get(groupPosition).get(childPosition);

    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ModelChild childTerbaru = getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
        ViewHolder holder= null;

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_child, null);

            holder=new ViewHolder();
            holder.begdate1=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_listchild);
            holder.enddate1=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_listchilds);
            convertView.setTag(holder);


        }
        else{
            holder=(ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.begdate1.setText(childTerbaru.getCat_id());
        holder.enddate1.setText(childTerbaru.getSub_category_name_en());

        return convertView;
    }
    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {

        return ListChildTerbaru.get(groupPosition).size();
    }

    @Override
    public ModelGroup getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return ListTerbaru.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return ListTerbaru.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ModelGroup terbaruModel = (ModelGroup) getGroup(groupPosition);
        ViewHolder holder= null;
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);

            holder=new ViewHolder();
            holder.nama=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_listtitle);
            holder.alamat=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_listtitles);
            convertView.setTag(holder);

        }

        else{
            holder=(ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.nama.setText(terbaruModel.getCat_name());
        holder.alamat.setText(terbaruModel.getCat_id());

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int arg0, int arg1) {
        return true;
    }


    static class ViewHolder{
        TextView begdate1, enddate1,nama, alamat, imageid;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/Put the below line of code inside your getChildView of adapter/

final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);


and Copy and paste the below override method inside adapter
@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon)
{
    return this.modelchild.get(this. modelgroup.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosititon);
}
```

Comment: I Edited my question @Yash

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public ModelChild getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return this.ListChildTerbaru.get(this.ListChildTerbaru.groupPosition).get(childPosition);

}

/Now in getChildView/

final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

 Log.i("Adapter", "getChildView childText: "+childText);

  if (convertView == null){
   ----
   -----
   }
```